# How to join two tables, one with values, one with labels, using column name as parameter

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables: one with coded (numeric answers) from surveys, and one with the column name, values, and their labels. Here are the sample tables:

Reference Table:

| Column | Value | Label |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Gender | 1 | Masc |
| Gender | 2 | Fem |
| Age | 1 | 17 or less |
| Age | 2 | 18-24 |
| Age | 3 | 25-44 |
| Age | 4 | 45-64 |
| Age | 5 | 65 or more |
| Q01 | 1 | Single |
| Q01 | 2 | Married |
| Q01 | 3 | Divorced |
| Q02 | 1 | Everyday |
| Q02 | 2 | Twice a week |
| Q02 | 3 | Once a month |
| Q02 | 4 | 3 times or less a year |

Data Table:

| RespondentID | Date | Name | Age | Gender | Q01 | Q02 | Q03 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023/06/14 | John | 2 | 1 | 2 | 4 | 3 |
| 2 | 2023/06/15 | Mary | 3 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 7 |

Desired Output Table:

| RespondentID | Date | Name | Age | tAge | Gender | tGender | Q01 | tQ01 | Q02 | tQ02 | Q03 | tQ03 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023/06/14 | John | 2 | 18-24 | 1 | Masc | 2 | Married | 4 | 3 times or less a year | 3 | XXX |
| 2 | 2023/06/15 | Mary | 3 | 25-44 | 2 | Fem | 3 | Divorced | 1 | Everyday | 7 | YYY |

I have about 65 variables to add labels. Can you recommend the most optimal query to accomplish this? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You can add select with subselect. Example:
Select 
Date, 
Name, 
Age, 
(select Label from Reference_Table where Value = Age and Column = 'Age') as tAge, 
Gender, 
...
from Desired_output_table

Comment: This is what I am doing now. But somehow it feels this is not the ideal approach, that's why I reached out...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  dt.RespondentID,
  dt.Date,
  dt.Name,
  dt.Age,
  rtAge.Label AS tAge,
  dt.Gender,
  rtGender.Label AS tGender,
  dt.Q01,
  rtQ01.Label AS tQ01,
  dt.Q02,
  rtQ02.Label AS tQ02,
  dt.Q03,
  rtQ03.Label AS tQ03
FROM
  data_table dt
LEFT JOIN
  reference_table rtAge ON rtAge.Column = 'Age' AND rtAge.Value = dt.Age
LEFT JOIN
  reference_table rtGender ON rtGender.Column = 'Gender' AND rtGender.Value = dt.Gender
LEFT JOIN
  reference_table rtQ01 ON rtQ01.Column = 'Q01' AND rtQ01.Value = dt.Q01
LEFT JOIN
  reference_table rtQ02 ON rtQ02.Column = 'Q02' AND rtQ02.Value = dt.Q02
LEFT JOIN
  reference_table rtQ03 ON rtQ03.Column = 'Q03' AND rtQ03.Value = dt.Q03;
```